# Paste special works intermittently

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am trying to do the following:

1. Filter the data in a worksheet
2. Copy the filtered data into a second worksheet

While the paste special works well for some filters, it does not work for others.  I have found that it does not work when the number of rows exceeds 50000.  Is there a workaround for this?

I am currently using to code:

```
selection.copy sheet10.range("A1")
```

to copy the contents into the new sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation of Problem

[Excel 2010 can select a maximum of 2048 ranges](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx). Each range is an unbroken rectangular area. I believe this limitation affects copying a filtered range. Every non-visible row in the filtered table splits the areas above and below into separate ranges. So if you have 4097 rows of data and you filter out every second row, you'll hit Excel's limit. Any additional rows will not copy correctly. I'm guessing here from the limited information you've provided. You've not said what the results are when it doesn't work.

### Potential Workaround

Instead of using only a filter, you could insert a new column with a formula that returns a true/false value based on the filter criteria. Then sort the table on that column before filtering. By sorting the table first you ensure all your visible data is in a contiguous range, and so instead of copying 2048+ ranges, you only copy one.

For example, if I want to filter Column A for anything starting with "Cat" and Column B for anything less than 5, I might write a formula:

```
=AND(LEFT(A2,3)="Cat", B2<5)
```

I can then sort on that column then filter for TRUE.

Comment: My apologies...yes...you are right...when it does not work, excel copies the whole contents of the sheet onto the new sheet. Ill try this and let you know how it works...thanks!  However, one problem I think i may encounter is the fact that using an if then loop over a huge dataset (for flagging) might hinder the speed of the dashboard...any thoughts there?

Comment: I wouldn't use an if-then statement in a loop in VBA, if that's what you mean. I'd use an in-cell formula to categorize my rows. I'd set the entire formula column at once (`Sheet1.[B1:B50].Formula = "=AND(A1<5, A1>2)`", call `Application.Calculate`, then overwrite the formulas with their calculated values `Sheet1.[B1:B50] = Sheet1.[B1:B50].Value` before I sorted the data.

Comment: Thanks....a lot...I am currently dynamically updating the pivot table for all the cases where the numbr of ranges exceeds 2048...but i do not want to use it as the tool is huge and i want to use a uniform logic...

Comment: You're using a pivot table? Was that part of your original design, have you been filtering and copying from a pivot table all along? That could change your options for sorting and extracting the data...

Comment: Yes and No. It was part of the original design in that I did intend to display data on a pivot. It was not part of the plan to filter the contents using a dynamic report filter.  For sorting, I am designing a small button that will provide VBA commands to sort a particular column....